# Hide and Show Masterview controller in UISplitview Controller

Tags: ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

I am very new to iPad application development. In my app I need to show a split view controller. In one scenario I need to hide and show the MasterView controller and show Details view controller 100%. Is it possible? Please help me.

Thanks in advance,
Chandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it possible, you can find more details here:

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/11/16/mail-app-style-split-view-controller-with-a-sliding-master-v.html